# Using Date in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have various `Date` instances in my `Java` program. Working with the is a pain but it is required.

```
Date today = new Date(); // Wed Dec 10 14:10:29 EST 2014

Date a = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 11, 10).getTime();
Date b = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 01, 10).getTime();
Date c = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 10).getTime();
Date d = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 03, 10).getTime(); //Fri April 10 00:00:00 EDT 2015
Date e = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 11 ,10).getTime();
```

I need to figure out how to shave off the time (14:10:29) from each as well as convert them to GMT time.

I know `today.getTime();` will the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, but I'm not sure how to represent that with out the times.

This would be for easier comparisons between dates. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do `Date a = new GregorianCalendar(...)` because `Date` is not a supertype of `GregorianCalendar`.

Comment: Also, `Calendar` months are 0-based so 0 = January, 1 = February, ..., 11 = December. And integer literals that start with 0 such as `01`, `02` are interpreted as octal, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Jesper GregorianCalendar seems to be working fine with the calculations I currently use it with, in addition to the Dates

Comment: Oh wait, I see you're calling `getTime()` on the `GregorianCalendar` objects which indeed returns a `Date`.

Comment: About the octal numbers: Try `09`, you'll see it will not compile.

Comment: @Jesper you are certainly right about that

Comment: @Jesper the only reason I chose to use GregorianCalendar was so I could hard code year, month, day. In production it will be grabbing `Dates` from a database

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is modulus the long value by the long value of 1 day, and subtract that off the long value of your date.

If you have Wed Dec 10 14:10:29 EST 2014, then if you do

```
Date today = new Date(); // Wed Dec 10 14:10:29 EST 2014
long timeDiff = today.getTime() % 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
today = new Date(today.getTime - timeDiff);
```

The new today object will be created with the time of the day removed.

To convert them to GMT you can similarly create new dates for the longs. This is obviously "Date" way to do it. The best way would be to use Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

try using date formater

```
SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss");
df.format(date)
```